# Generating a histogram

Tags: c++, histogram

I have a problem in generating a histogram. I have got a set of data which i want to be counted and stored in a file in order to make in excel a diagram, just like an image histogram.

Here is my code but I get the right number of data in total, but not the frequency how often. I have set the width of the histogram to 0.01 thats only a test later I have to improve it.

```
void TPictureWindow::Histogramm()
{
  unsigned long retval;
  char buffer[100];

  int valueHist[260];
  int finalVal;
  double value = 0.0;
  double histWidth = 0.01;
  int counter = 0;
  scaling = 0.005078125;

  HANDLE hDataFile = CreateFile("Histogramm.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

  for(int i = 0; i < NumImages; i++)
  {

    for(int j = 0; j < edge[i][0]->total; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0;k < sizeof(valueHist);k++){

           CvPoint* pt1 = CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint, edge[i][0], j);
           CvPoint* pt2 = CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint, edge[i][1], j);

           value = (pt1->y-pt2->y)*scaling;

           if(value < 0) value = 0.0;

           finalVal = value/histWidth;
        //sprintf(buffer, "final: %d\nvalue: %f\n", finalVal, value);
        //MessageBox(buffer, "", MB_OK);



           if(finalVal == k){

              counter++;
              valueHist[k] = counter;
              sprintf(buffer, "%9.3d\n", valueHist[k]);
              WriteFile(hDataFile, buffer, strlen(buffer), &retval, NULL);
           }
        }
     }


 }
 CloseHandle(hDataFile);
 PostMessage(READY_WITH, IMG_3D_PROFILE, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the value to calculate its bin instead of searching for the bin should be both easier and faster.

```
for(int i = 0; i < NumImages; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < edge[i][0]->total; j++) {
       CvPoint* pt1 = CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint, edge[i][0], j);
       CvPoint* pt2 = CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint, edge[i][1], j);
       int bin

       value = (pt1->y-pt2->y)*scaling;

       if(value < 0) value = 0.0;

       int bin = floor(value/binSize);

       if ( bin < maxBin ) {
          hist[bin] = hist[bin] + 1;
       } else {
        /* Report a lost point if interested */
      }
    }
 }
```

You will loose points if maxBin * binSize < max(value).